# How can i add a formula field into a Opportunity Product Multi-Line Layout

Tags: administration, opportunity-lineitem

I have a formula field on Opportunity Product which i need to show on the Opportunity product Mulitline Edit page. I cant seem to get the formulafield on the available Fields List.

I understand that we cant see a formula field on edit or new records and hence maybe these fields are not visible. Am i correct ?

Is there any other way we could get it displayed?

Thanks

**EDIT**
As e-bacho 2.0 mentioned i would also think VF page could be the only option.
If we are using VF page, how do we get the Products selected from Product Selection page into new VF page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is possible with custom visualforce page which you'll need to override the standard edit page with.

Hope this will help - [Overriding a Standard Button](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/cookbook/Content/vf_override_button.htm)

Also : [This Video](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/05/02/overriding-standard-links-buttons-in-salesforce-com/)

Comment: Thanks.. I thought so too.. That brings up the question how does the VF page capture the selected products from the previous screen. any pointers?